# Exposing Spring-WS

Tags: spring, jax-ws

ws. Iam using tomcat7 to deploy my app wich is made with spring3. I already get my ws to work but now i need it to run on the same port of the tomcat, every time i setup the base address for the simpleJaxWsServiceExporter with the same port of the tomcat, both the application and the web service crash an i get a 404 error code.

here is my code for the ws so far

```
@Bean
public SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter simpleJaxWsServiceExporter() {
    SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter bean = new SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter();
    bean.setBaseAddress("http://mydomain:5900/");       
    return bean;
}

@Component
```

@WebService(serviceName = "ProblemService")
public class ProblemService{

```
@Autowired
private ProblemDAO problemDAO;

@WebMethod
public String getProblemByAbb(@WebParam(name = "abb")String name){
    return "Hola "+name;
}
```

}